# Multiple alert boxes instead of one

Tags: php

I have a simple `PHP` issues, it's causing unneccesary spam of alert boxes. I'm trying to show 1 alert box with the errors instead every error has it's own alert box which is causing spam.

```
<?php  
if (!empty($errors)){
    foreach($errors as $error){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("'. $error .'\n")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Help is appreciated and comment on what went wrong, I know it has something to do with the foreach but I tried looking up what to replace `foreach` with.

Comment: it's because its looping the alert, so for each error show a box, what you should do is have a base string and for each error add the error to the string, then after the string has been completed, do the javascript alert

Comment: Them dont Call alert inside your loop. Instead you should append a string and outside the loop Call alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make 1 alert.  In the loop, print out each error:

```
<?php  
if (!empty($errors)){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("';
    foreach($errors as $error){            
        echo $error.'\n';
    }

    echo '");</script>';

}
?>
```

Comment: this will add the literal text of `<br/>` after each error...just fyi

Comment: @jh314 That doesn't alert at all, I'll look into the code more.

Comment: @jh314 That did the trick, what was the problem if I may ask? Edit: I see now, the quotation marks and the dot.

Answer (score 1):

I for one don't think this is a good way to go about showing errors but you could do this:

```
<?php  
if (!empty($errors)){
    $i = 0;
    $errorString = "";
    foreach($errors as $error){
        $i++;
        $errorString .= "$i) $error\n";
    }
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("'. $errorString .'\n")';
    echo '</script>';
}
?>
```